# Sort doubly linked list with just manipulating pointers

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Given doubly linked list $L$ that contains $n$ elements of numbers. Between QuickSort, and MergeSort and InsertionSort, which algorithm preferred to sorting $L$ by just swapping links of $L$?

I think the InsertionSort is better option but I have no any idea  to show that that minimize number of changing pointers. Any help will appreciated?

Suppose in below black edge is previous link and green edge is next link, after swapping liknks:
[image]

Comment: Are you allowed to use nonconstant external working memory? Are you allowed to temporarily make a copy of a number outside of L?

Comment: Yes we are allowed to use auxiliary memory.

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami Suppose a node is a pair of pointers $(n, p)$ where $n$ points to the next node and $p$ points to the previous node (and the data part is omitted). Suppose there are nodes $e_1:=(n_1\to e_2, p_1\to e_0)$, $e_2:=(n_2\to e_3, p_2\to e_1)$, $e_7:=(n_7\to e_8, p_7\to e_6)$, $e_8:=(n_8\to e_9, p_8\to e_7)$, where the arrows are understood naturally. What is a swap of links/a change of pointers? Can you give an example with the setup here, showing the result of one change of pointers?

Comment: @JohnL. I add an example.

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami Should node 1 and node 2 be adjacent in a swap?

Comment: 1) Exactly which swaps do you make to achieve what you show in the picture? You can't achieve this by only swapping the pointers (i.e. if the operation is to swap the values in 2 pointers), since in the original picture pointer to $4$ occurs twice, but in the sorted version it occurs once. 2) Do you need to find the exact minimum number of swaps (i.e. current answers which only show $O(n)$ sequence when $O(1)$ sequence exists don't answer your question)?

Comment: @JohnL. Adjacency of elements doesn't change we just change pointer.

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami Aha.  Thanks. That is the point of pointers: positions do not change; only pointers change.

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing the number of changing pointers is equivalent to minimizing number of swaps, which is obtained by Selection Sort.

Answer (score 0):

Only MergeSort has a guaranteed $O(n\log n)$ behavior.
You may well consider Natural MergeSort, that has the extra property of adaptiveness.

---

If you only care about swapping links (?), I guess that both StraightSelection and StraightInsertion achieve an optimal (certainly in the worst case, $O(n)$).

Comment: Why you think insertion sort is optimal?

Comment: It moves every element once, doesn't it ?

Comment: But eac pointer could be changed multiple times over each insertion. How it change each pointer one time?

Comment: @Jut: how could it change multiple times ??

Comment: Suppose $L=\langle 1,3,-1,2\rangle$, then we do nothing about $1$ and $2$, but we insert $-1$ before $1$ and $3$ after next iteration we insert $2$ between $1$ and $3$, so we change multiple times the pointer of $1$ and $3$.

Comment: @Jut: in what way does that differ from StraightSelection ?

Comment: Could you explain why you sense that your guess is true?

Answer (score 0):

Selection sort will sort in O(n^2) with O(n) pointer changes. So if for some reason you need to minimise the number of pointer changes, that’s it.

On the other hand, you can just put all the pointers into an array, sort the array, and reconstruct the double linked list.

(I actually had this in a job interview. I recommended either this, or bubble sort if it is absolutely not time critical because bubble sort of a double linked list is fun).

Comment: Could you argue that how Selection sort needs $O(n)$ pointer changes?

Comment: Selection sort will need O(n) pointer changes in most cases, and not more. It is very unusual that you measure the number of pointer changes and nothing else.

Comment: Can we claim that, Merge sort needs $O(n\log n)$ pointer changes?